# Testing a function which save some configuration - error called set on null

Tags: 8, configuration, testing

I have a function which does 2-3 things, one of the activity is to save the configuration.

```
function processProps($data) {
  $config = $this->configFactory->getEditable('mymodule.settings');
  $config
    ->set('some_setting', 'some value')
    ->set('another_setting', 'another value')
    ->save();
  ...
  return TRUE;
}
```

The test code as follows

```
public function testSspProcessProperties() {
    $data = $this->getTestData();

    $immutable_config_object = $this->prophesize(ImmutableConfig::class);
    $immutable_config_object->isNew()->willReturn(FALSE);

    $config_object = $this->prophesize(Config::class);
    $config_object
      ->setData([
        'key' => 'value',
      ])
      ->shouldBeCalled();
    $config_object->save(FALSE)->shouldBeCalled();
    $config_object->get()->willReturn([]);

    $this->configFactory->loadMultiple(['mymodule.settings'])
      ->willReturn([]);
    $this->configFactory
      ->get('mymodule.settings')
      ->willReturn($immutable_config_object->reveal());

    $this->configFactory->getEditable('mymodule.settings')
      ->willReturn($config_object->reveal());

    $this->assertTrue($this->myclass->processProps($data));
  }
```

This test gives error `Error: Call to a member function set() on null`.
When I debug found that `$config` object is loaded properly. So not able to understand why I say null :(

I checked [ConfigEntityStorageTest](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21tests%21Drupal%21Tests%21Core%21Config%21Entity%21ConfigEntityStorageTest.php/function/ConfigEntityStorageTest%3A%3AtestSaveUpdate/8.8.x) for the reference.

Comment: One question - your test asserts that the method returns true, but the code provided looks like it will always return true regardless. I assume there is some redacted code there that has return false?

Comment: @Kevin It's probably the `...`, but it would be clearer if the OP included the code in the post.